# Matchmaker's problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a past exam exercise I'm unable to solve.

$B$ is finite set.

$h:B\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(G)$ where $\mathcal{P}(G)$ is the powerset of $G$ with the following properties:

1. for every $x\in B$, $h(x)$ is a finite subset of $G$
2. $X\subseteq B\rightarrow |X|\leq|\cup \{h(x):x\in X\}|$

I would like to prove that there exists a monomorphism $f:B\rightarrow G$ such that

$(\forall x\in B)[f(x)\in h(x)]$.

Is this known as "the matchmaker's problem?"

Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: By a "monomorphism" you just mean an injective function, right? I'm not sure what you're asking. You just want to know if that theorem is known as "the matchmaker's problem"? Or you want some hints on how to prove it? Or you want a proof? A reference? Do you need a proof from first principles, or have you learned some related theorem that can be used? (Anent the first question, I haven't heard it called "the matchmaker's problem", though that seems like a good name for it; have you tried Startpaging or Duckduckgoing for that phrase?)

Comment: @bof Exactly an injective function. Feel free to use any theorem. A proof or some hints would be nice. Thank you!

Comment: In that particular formulation I know it as Hall's Theorem, but there are a number of equivalent or closely related formulations named after other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as [Hall's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem). Here is a proof by induction on $|B|.$ The theorem is trivial if $B=\emptyset,$ so we assume that $|B|\ge1.$ For $X\subseteq B$ define $h(X)=\bigcup\{h(x):x\in X\}.$ Define a "critical set" to be a set $C\subseteq B\ $ such that $|C|=|h(C)|, C\ne\emptyset,$ and $C\ne B.$ We consider two cases, depending on whether or not there is a critical set.

**Case I. There is no critical set.** In other words, $|X|\lt|h(X)|$ whenever $\emptyset\ne X\subsetneq B\ $. Choose $b\in B$ and $g\in h(b)$. Let $B'=B\setminus\{b\}$, and define $h':B'\to\mathcal P(G)$ by setting $h'(x)=h(x)\setminus\{g\}\ $ for $x\in B'$. Then conditions 1 & 2 hold with $B$ and $h$ replaced by $B'$ and $h'$. By the induction hypothesis, there is an injection $f':B'\to G$ such that $f'(x)\in h'(x)$ for all $x\in B'.$ Now the function $f=f'\cup\{(b,g)\}$ does the job.

**Case II. There is a critical set.** I.e., there is a set $C$ such that $\emptyset\ne C\subsetneq B$ and $|C|=|h(C)|.$ By the induction hypothesis, there is an injection $f_C:C\to G$ such that $f_C(x)\in h(x)$ for all $x\in C$. Let $B'=B\setminus C$. Define $h':B'\to\mathcal P(G)$ by setting $h'(x)=h(x)\setminus h(C)$ for $x\in B'.$ Then conditions 1 & 2 hold with $B$ and $h$ replaced by $B'$ and $h'$. By the induction hypothesis, there is an injection $f':B'\to G$ such that $f'(x)\in h'(x)$ for all $x\in B'.$ Now the function $f=f'\cup f_C$ does the job.